# How to develop XNA projects without registering the Xbox360 kinect on my PC

Tags: xna, kinect, xbox360

I want to develop an XNA project to create augmented reality. I have the xbox360 Kinect sensor with me but when I try to debug it, it gives me the error saying :-
Error 1 No devices are available to deploy project 'Xbox360Game1'. Register a device using the XNA Game Studio Device Center. Am I doing something wrong or do I need a game console to debug the project or isn't it impossible to debug projects only with Kinect sensor and visual Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've created an Xbox 360 Game Project, instead of a Windows Game Project.

The quick solution would be to right click your game project in Solution Explorer, and select "Create Copy of Project for Windows". This will give you a duplicate, syncronised project that targets Windows.

I'm not sure how this interacts with Kinect. You might need to fix up some references or something.